# Equivalent datatype to TBXML for C#

Tags: c#, tbxml

Is there any similar datatype that I can use to save data in C# in the same way it is saved in TBXML Objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling `TBXML` shows an XML parser. If this is the case, C# does have XML-parsing capabilities in the `System.Xml` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can store (virtually) any datatype using XmlSerializer see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

You can specify whether a property of an object is to be stored using property attributes otherwise the serializer will use reflection to store the whole object.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes for a decent tutorial

Comment: If you are trying to pass data from one app to the other i.e. TBXML to c# then you will have to write a mapping class probably.